# Access data within a SQL Server cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to access the temp data created within a SQL Server cursor? I would like to set some conditions within the cursor but those depends on the data that the cursor has example:

Cursor declaration.....

```
if (@Column = (SELECT MAX(ID) from cursor_name/table where Rid = @Rid))
begin
    ....
```

I'm actually doing this using a table variable that is being read by the cursor but I wonder if there's a better way to achieve this, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Just place that in your cursor. Usually you store the current cursor value in a variable so just check that variable against your sub query

Comment: Show the actually thing you want to do. Perhaps cursor is not neccessary.

Comment: thanks @scsimon that's how I'm doing it right now using the table variable inside the cursor comparing the result of the column variable vs the subquery from the table variable but I wonder if there's a way to do a subquery directly from cursor instead of creating a variable table and do it from there, it's working so far just wondering if there's a most efficient way.

Comment: @TriV, yes i need the cursor as I'm using dynamic sql to create a query based on columns selected by the user, I was using a while loop but I did realize that the cursor fast forward is better